# detecting the index of silence from a given audio file using python

Tags: python, audio

I am trying to process an audio file in python using various modules like numpy, struct etc. But I am really having a hard time detecting silence in the file, as in where is the presence of silence. one on the methods I came across was to slide a window of fixed time interval over my audio signal and record the sum of squared elements. I am new to python and hardly aware of it thus unable to implement this method.

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried so far?  Otherwise, this is a very broad question that will be hard to answer specifically.

Answer (score 13):

If you are open to outside libraries, one of the quick ways to do this is using [pydub](https://pydub.com).

`pydub` has a module called [silence](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/pydub/silence.py) that has methods  `detect_silence` and `detect_nonsilent` that may be useful in your case.

However, the only caveat is that silence needs to be at least half a second.

Below is a sample implementation that I tried using an audio file.

However, since silence in my case was less than half a second, only a few of the silent ranges were correct.

You may want to try this and see if it works for you by tweaking `min_silence_len` and `silence_thresh`.

**Program**

```
from pydub import AudioSegment, silence

myaudio = AudioSegment.from_wav("a-z-vowels.wav")

silence = silence.detect_silence(myaudio, min_silence_len=1000, silence_thresh=-16)

silence = [((start/1000),(stop/1000)) for start,stop in silence] #convert to sec

print(silence)
```

**Result**

```
[(0, 1), (1, 14), (14, 20), (19, 26), (26, 27), (28, 30), (29, 32), (32, 34), (33, 37), (37, 41), (42, 46), (46, 47), (48, 52)]
```

Comment: Note that pydub's silence detector is extremely slow. On a 30 minute piece of audio that takes Audacity about 1 second to detect and remove silences, it takes pydub about 2 minutes.

Comment: @JohnWiseman would you instead suggest using Audacity for this task? What if I need to create a pipeline and need to do batch work, could Audacity be a candidate component?

Comment: my first project when working as developer =))))) It was 3 years ago. Thanks all
`silence = [((start/1000),(stop/1000)) for start,stop in silence] #convert to sec` 100%, word for word

Answer (score 13):

For better result use dBFS

```
from pydub import AudioSegment,silence

myaudio = intro = AudioSegment.from_mp3("RelativityOverview.mp3")
dBFS=myaudio.dBFS
silence = silence.detect_silence(myaudio, min_silence_len=1000, silence_thresh=dBFS-16)

silence = [((start/1000),(stop/1000)) for start,stop in silence] #in sec
print(silence)
```

Comment: The dBFS really improved the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import wave, time
    import numpy as np
    with wave.open(filename, 'r') as wav_file:
        signal = wav_file.readframes(-1)
        channels = [{} for _ in range(wav_file.getnchannels())]
        fs = wav_file.getframerate()
    signal = np.frombuffer(signal, dtype='int16')

    def_sile, sile_upto = signal // 5, fs // 44
```

> 5, 44, 3 can be other suitable integer
>
> a frame is quiet if its value (datum variable below) is bigger than def_sile
>
> a second is quiet if number of quiet frames in that second is bigger than sile_upto

```
    tongsoframe = len(signal) // len(channels)
    dodaiaudio = tongsoframe // fs


    for index, datum in enumerate(signal):
        if datum > def_sile:
            mocthoigian: int = index//len(channels)//fs
            if mocthoigian not in channels[index % len(channels)]:
                channels[index % len(channels)][mocthoigian]: list = list()
            channels[index % len(channels)][mocthoigian].append(datum)
    silent_second_list = list()
    for tg in range(dodaiaudio):
        if tg not in channels[0]:
            silent_second_list.append(tg)
            continue
        numberofframes: int = len(channels[0][tg])
        # numberofframes là số frames có tín hiệu trên mốc im lặng trong giây thứ tg
        if numberofframes < sile_upto:
            # nếu numberofframes dưới mốc tối đa sile_upto -> nằm trong giới hạn im lặng
            silent_second_list.append(tg)

    print(silent_second_list)
```