# How to find where the silence begins from an audio starting from certain timestamp?

Tags: python, audio, pydub

I'm trying to index an audio file at a certain non-silent timestamp, say 20 seconds from the beginning (0:20:00), and find the closest timestamp from there that silence begins, say 21 seconds from the beginning (0:21:00).

I'm aware that `pydub` has `detect_silence` feature that may be useful but not sure how to index an audio file using timestamp. I'm open to using other libraries as well.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem. You may use `detect_silence` to get all regions (as list with pairs `(start, end)`) and later search on list first pair which have start bigger than `0:20:00`

Comment: diging in source code I found you can use slice `[start:end]` to get some region - `audio{20_000:]` gives audio at 20second.

Comment: you can read my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896370/detecting-the-index-of-silence-from-a-given-audio-file-using-python/78241789#78241789 for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it but

`detect_silence` gives list with pairs `(start, end)` so you could run on original audio and later search this list to find first pair which have `start` bigger than `0:20:00` (or rather bigger than `20_000`)

But it can use slice `[start:end]` to work only with some part of audio.

```
part = audio[20_000:]
```

It could look like this

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.silence import detect_silence

audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3("your_audio.mp3")
part = audio[20_000:]

chunks = detect_silence(part, ... other options ...)

print('start in part :', chunks[0][0])
print('start in audio:', chunks[0][0] + 20_000)
```