# Send audio chunks to the websocket server on silence

Tags: python, websocket, celery, fastapi, whisper

I am sending audio chunks to the server by counting the number of chunks. If the number of chunks reaches 20, I convert them into base64 and then send them to the server for transcription. However, instead of counting the chunks, I want to detect silence in the chunks. If there is silence lasting for more than 2-3 seconds, I want to send the chunks to the server for transcription until that point.
this is code that I am using to count the chunks.

```
user_stats = {}
user_audio = {}
user_chunk_num = {}
async def transcribe(websocket: WebSocket, token: str = Query(...), format: Optional[str] =None):
    while True:
           filnam="websocket token"
            # Receive audio chunk from the client
            audio_chunk = await websocket.receive()

           # Count number of chunks 
            elif('bytes' in audio_chunk):
                if(filnam in user_audio):
 
                    user_chunk_num[filnam] += 1
                    if(format =='webm'):
                        user_audio[filnam] = user_audio[filnam] + audio_chunk['bytes']
                    else:
                        wav1 = BytesIO(audio_chunk['bytes'])
                        newseg = AudioSegment.from_file(wav1)
                        user_audio[filnam] = user_audio[filnam] + newseg
                else:
                    user_chunk_num[filnam] = 0
                    # chunk_n=0
                    if(format == 'webm'):
                        user_audio[filnam] = audio_chunk['bytes']             
                    else:
                        wav1 = BytesIO(audio_chunk['bytes'])
                        newseg = AudioSegment.from_file(wav1)
                        user_audio[filnam] = newseg
            print (f"Got chunk # for {filnam}", user_chunk_num[filnam])
            if(user_chunk_num[filnam] % 20 == 0 and user_chunk_num[filnam] > 0):
                
                # convert the chunks into base 64 
                audio_data = audio_base64(filnam, user_chunk_num[filnam], format)
                # transcribe the audio
                task = transcribe_task.delay(audio_data)
                print(f"Current time {cr_time}")
                flag_=True
            if(filnam in user_chunk_num and  user_chunk_num[filnam] >= 20):
                if(task.state == "SUCCESS"):
                    result = task.get()
                    print('inside flag')
                    task.forget()
                    task.revoke()
                    await websocket.send_json({"transcript" :result, "final":True,"time_3":cr_time,"length":len(user_audio[filnam])})
                    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
                else:
                    await websocket.send_json({"final":False, "ack":True, "status":"PENDING"})
```

I would be grateful for any help from anyone

Comment: Why are you doing this chunking?  Why are you converting to base64?  You can send binary data over a websocket.  And `if` statements in Python do not use parentheses.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for comment. if no. of chunks is equal to 20 or multiple of 20 then I am transcribing them. instead of counting the chunks i want to detect the silence and then send it for transcription.

Comment: You know how to detect silence, right?  You look for a long string of zeros in the data.

Comment: If this is data captured from a microphone, you'll have to decide what "silence" really is. A microphone will keep capturing ambient noise from the surroundings, so generally you'll never see a long running sequence of zeroes. Instead, decide a cut-off-point for amplitude, and check whether a chunk has crossed that in any locations (or a given % crosses the limit). `pydub` can help with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896370/detecting-the-index-of-silence-from-a-given-audio-file-using-python (see dBFS)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.